# How do I programmatically set a database connection?

Tags: database, 9

Hello can anybody help with a external Database Connection.

```
$postgis_database = array(
        'database' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getdatabase(),
        'username' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getusername(),
        'password' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getpassword(),
        'host' => $drugis_postgis_connection->gethost(),
        'driver' => 'pgsql',

    );
    Database::setActiveConnection('postgis','default', $postgis_database);
    \Drupal::database();
    $info = Database::getConnection();
    dpm($info);
```

$info is the default connection, i don't know how to connect to 'postgis' connection

Comment: Why isn't this a part of the databases array in settings.PHP? What is the error?

Comment: There is no error. getConnectionInfo(); show me the default database. This is part of config entity connection modul for multiple database connections. I can't switch to 'postgis'

Comment: There is no [setActiveConnection](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Database.php/function/Database%3A%3AsetActiveConnection/9.0.x) with more than one parameter. Take a look at [Database::addConnectionInfo](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Database.php/function/Database%3A%3AaddConnectionInfo/9.0.x). You really should try to get a proper IDE with code completition up and running (like VS Code or PHPStorm), you don't have to blindly guess function parameters, an IDE will answer questions like these on the fly.

Comment: You can declare multiple database connections in settings.php, and switch between then https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/instantiating-a-database-connection-object#s-using-a-different-database-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Database::setActiveConnection()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Database.php/function/Database%3A%3AsetActiveConnection/9.1.x) just sets as active connection a connection defined in the settings.php file, or added from a previous call to [`Database::addConnectionInfo()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Database.php/function/Database%3A%3AaddConnectionInfo/9.1.x).

The correct code would be the following one.

```php
$postgis_database = [
  'database' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getdatabase(),
  'username' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getusername(),
  'password' => $drugis_postgis_connection->getpassword(),
  'host' => $drugis_postgis_connection->gethost(),
  'driver' => 'pgsql',
];

//                          $key      $target
Database::addConnectionInfo('postgis','default', $postgis_database);
//                            $target    $key
Database::setActiveConnection('default', 'postgis');
```

Notice the parameters order in the last two method calls. Notice also the array index order used in the `$database` array set in the settings.php file.

```php
//         $key       $target
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => 'databasename',
  'username' => 'sqlusername',
  'password' => 'sqlpassword',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'prefix' => '',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
 ];
```

The connections added with `Database::addConnectionInfo()` aren't permanent; they are added to the static property of the `Database` class. All the functions/methods that want to use the connection defined in `$postgis_database` needs to execute the code I showed before querying the database or saving values in the database.
It's probably better to add the extra connections in the settings.

An error to avoid is calling Drupal functions that query a specific Drupal database table after calling `Database::setActiveConnection('default', 'postgis')`. For example, calling [`taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name/9.1.x) after `Database::setActiveConnection('default', 'postgis')` won't work, except in the case the postgis/default database contains a copy of the tables used from Drupal. (Usually, that isn't the case, as a module using a different database isn't going to make a copy of the tables Drupal expects to find, in that database.)
Before calling functions like `taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name()`, the code should call `Database::setActiveConnection()`, which restores the active connection to the default one used by Drupal, which is for a database containing all the tables used from Drupal.

Comment: Thank you very much I forget to copy the addConnectionInfo method in here and wrote instead of this the parameter in setActiveConnection().  But know with the key and the target in setActiveConnection it work. Thanks